# Is it possible to enforce a manager filter based on a variable in django?

Tags: django

We would like to enforce a specific filter in a django application as a way to prevent accidental data leaking (and to require developers to be explicit about intention).

Lets say we have a Project model and a Book model, and we want to prevent `Book.objects.all()` without filtering on a project.

I would like something like this:

```
Book.objects.for_project(project) -> Should return a QuerySet with all books for a specific project
Book.objects.all_projects() -> Should return a QuerySet with all books, i.e. for usage in data migration commands
Book.objects.all_projects().filter() -> Should be chainable
Book.objects.all() -> Should throw a DataLeakError()
Book.objects.filter() -> Should throw a DataLeakError()
Book.objects.exclude() -> Should throw a DataLeakError()
Book.objects.only() -> Should throw a DataLeakError()
....etc
```

Is there a standard pattern for something like this, or is this an anti-pattern?

Comment: you need to override the custom manager of the django

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question! You could certainly write a [custom manager method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset) to create methods like `all_projects()` and raise errors for a given method.

```
class Book(models.Model):
     objects = BookManager()
```

OR you could supply a secondary object manager like

```
class Book(models.Model):
     permission_objects = BookManager()
```

Which will still allow you to fetch all data via the ORM if there is an instance you need to to avoid this filterset.

```
class BookManager(models.Manager):
    def for_project(proj):
        return self.filter(project=proj)
```

> Is there a standard pattern for something like this, or is this an anti-pattern?

I think it depends on your app. Using custom manager methods is certainly not an anti-pattern. In Django Rest Framework- this is typically handled explicitly in a `permissions` layer (which may very well use custom manager methods!). However if you're dealing with standard views I think it's acceptable.

Granted..throwing errors on things like `.all()` might cause headaches you have to code around when dealing with some built-ins/shortcuts/plugins if you're using generic things like ViewSets for example.